# How to update progressbar of media controller android?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-video-player, mediacontroller

I'm trying to create a custom video playback, which has a video view  and media controller:

```
VideoView mVideoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);  

MediaController mMediaController = new MyMediaController(this);
mMediaController.findFocus();
mMediaController.setEnabled(true);
mMediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
```

Problem is that: when I programmatically change value of seekbar:

```
mVideoView.pause();
mVideoView.seekTo(newValue);
```

MediaController doesn't update these changes immediately. It updates only after I touch it again. Can anybody tell me the right way to update state of media controller? Thanks a a lot!

Answer (score 1):

for this you have to set an handler that is call after every one second like below code-

```
static Runnable musicSchedular = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       resetSeek();
    }
};

public static void resetSeek(){
   long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
   int cPos = (int)currentDuration/1000;
   seekBar.setProgress(cPos);
}
```

and when you start playing music paste this line of code

```
  myHandler.postDelayed(musicSchedular,100);
```

hope it will solve your problem.